# Cannot locate resource 'pages/edit/view'

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, hyperlink

I am displaying one page in my main window using Frame. Now in that particular page i am setting up datagrid programmatically. And this datagrid contains hyperlink. Now every time i click on that hyperlink i  get "Cannot locate resource" error. My page named page1.xaml is inside a folder "Pages". And "edit/view" is the text of that particular hyperlink. How do i resolve this? I want some action to be called from the page when the "edit/view" hyperlink is clicked. Thanks in advance.

Here the code in my mainwindow.xaml

```
//Displaying the Page1.xaml from frame in MainWindow
<Frame Source="/Pages/Page1.xaml"/>
```

Datagrid code in Page1.xaml

```
<DataGrid Height="479" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Margin="12,55,24,148" RowHeaderWidth="0" FontSize="12" Name="dgList" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" BorderBrush="#FFbab3b3" Background="White" Foreground="#FF565754" AlternatingRowBackground="#fffff5f6" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FFF8F8F8" VerticalGridLinesBrush="#FFbab3b3" IsReadOnly="True"  SelectionChanged="dgList_SelectionChanged" />
```

And this is how i setup datagrid in Page1.xaml.cs

```
public void SetupdgListDataGrid()
    {
        var col1 = new DataGridTextColumn();
        col1.Header = "Name";
        col1.Binding = new Binding("[0]");
        dgList.Columns.Add(col1);

        col1 = new DataGridTextColumn();
        col1.Header = "Age";
        col1.Binding = new Binding("[1]");
        dgList.Columns.Add(col1);


        try
        {
            var style1 = new Style(typeof(TextBlock));

            style1.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(Hyperlink.ClickEvent, (RoutedEventHandler)Event_ViewAction));

            var columnView = new DataGridHyperlinkColumn { Header = " ", Binding = new Binding("ViewUserLink"), ElementStyle = style1 };

            columnView.Binding = new Binding("[2]");

            dgList.Columns.Add(columnView);


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }



        this.dgList.ItemsSource = SomeDataSourceObject;



    }

    public void Event_ViewAction(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Edit clicked");
    }
```

And now my defination fro SomeDataSourceObject is as follows

```
List<object> SomeDataSourceObject = new List<object>();
```

And fill the data as below.

```
string[] tempValues = new string[3];

tempValues[0] = "FirstName";
tempValues[1] = "20";
tempValues[2] = "Edit/View";


SomeDataSourceObject.Add(tempValues);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're clicking to text "Edit/View" which is a string that is not linked with anything. If you  provide a correct resource (e.g a web URL) you'll be navigated to it.

You can also explicitly stop loading the content by using NavigationService:

```
public void Event_ViewAction(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  MessageBox.Show("Edit clicked");          
  this.NavigationService.StopLoading();         
}
```

However in case it should work just like a button I propose to add a classic button and style it as I wrote in the comment.

Comment: Ok thanks for the reply. But how do i call a method on hyper link click. For example the method "Event_ViewAction" or any other method.

Comment: DataGridHyperlinkColumn represents a DataGrid column that hosts Uri elements in its cells (by MSDN). In your case the hyperlink is clicked (the event handler is called) but it also starts a process of navigation to Uri. If you need just a button that looks like a link that use a DataGridTemplateColumn add a button to it and style it as an hyperlink. The easiest way would be the grid columns declaration directly in XAML.